# Getting color from Gradient at current mouse coordinates

Tags: qt, qml

Ok, user @tro has described one way, however, I've decided to:

1. Subclass [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html)
2. Reimplement its [requestImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#requestImage) method
3. Add image provider to [QQmlApplicationEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html) via [addImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImageProvider) method
4. On `QML` side, setup [MouseArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) and call [qml invokable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) `void UviColorPicker::getColorFromCoordinates(const qreal& coordX, const qreal& coordY)` method on every mouse mouse

Here is `ColorPicker` class:

```
#ifndef UVICOLORPICKER_H
#define UVICOLORPICKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QLinearGradient>
#include <QColor>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QSize>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QByteArray>

/**
 * @class Color picker class
 */
class UviColorPicker : public QObject,
                       public QQuickImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /**
     * @brief Color picker background gradient
     */
    QLinearGradient colorPickerBackgroundGradient;

    /**
     * @brief Color picker background brush
     */
    QBrush colorPickerBackgroundBrush;

    /**
     * @brief Color picker foreground gradient
     */
    QLinearGradient colorPickerForegroundGradient;

    /**
     * @brief Color picker foreground brush
     */
    QBrush colorPickerForegroundBrush;

    /**
     * @brief Color picker graphics scene
     */
    QGraphicsScene colorPickerGraphicsScene;

    /**
     * @brief Color picker image
     */
    QImage colorPickerImage;

private:
    /**
     * @brief Background gradient stops init method
     */
    void initBackgroundGradient();


    /**
     * @brief Foreground gradient stops init method
     */
    void initForegroundGradient();

public:
    /**
     * @brief Constructor
     * @param parent
     */
    explicit UviColorPicker(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR);

    /**
     * @brief Destructor
     */
    ~UviColorPicker();

    /**
     * @brief Image request method for QML side
     * @param id
     * @param size
     * @param requestedSize
     * @return color picker QImage
     */
    QImage requestImage(const QString& id,
                        QSize* size,
                        const QSize& requestedSize) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    /**
     * @brief Calculates color from coords and emits correspondent signals
     * @param coordX
     * @param coordY
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void getColorFromCoordinates(const qreal& coordX,
                                             const qreal& coordY);

Q_SIGNALS:
    /**
     * @brief Signal emitted when mouse coords change in color picker
     * @param redComponent
     * @param greenComponent
     * @param blueComponent
     */
    void signalPickedColorChanged(const quint8& redComponent,
                                  const quint8& greenComponent,
                                  const quint8& blueComponent);
};

#endif // UVICOLORPICKER_H
```

and its implementation:

```
#include "uvicolorpicker.h"

UviColorPicker::UviColorPicker(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                          QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading),
      colorPickerGraphicsScene(new QGraphicsScene(this)),
      colorPickerImage(QImage(QSize(256,
                                    256),
                                    QImage::Format_ARGB32))
{
    QPainter gradientPainter(this->colorPickerImage);

    gradientPainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    this->initBackgroundGradient();
    this->initForegroundGradient();

    this->colorPickerBackgroundBrush=QBrush(this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient);
    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->setBackgroundBrush(this->colorPickerBackgroundBrush);

    this->colorPickerForegroundBrush=QBrush(this->colorPickerForegroundGradient);
    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->setForegroundBrush(this->colorPickerForegroundBrush);

    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->render(&gradientPainter);
}

UviColorPicker::~UviColorPicker()
{
    delete this->colorPickerGraphicsScene;

    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene=Q_NULLPTR;
}

QImage UviColorPicker::requestImage(const QString& id,
                                    QSize* size,
                                    const QSize& requestedSize)
{
    Q_UNUSED(id)
    Q_UNUSED(size)
    Q_UNUSED(requestedSize)

    return this->colorPickerImage;
}

void UviColorPicker::getColorFromCoordinates(const qreal& coordX,
                                             const qreal& coordY)
{
    QColor detectedColor=this->colorPickerImage.pixel(coordX,
                                                       coordY);

    Q_EMIT this->signalPickedColorChanged(detectedColor.red(),
                                          detectedColor.green(),
                                          detectedColor.blue());

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "Color at"
             << " "
             << "("
             << coordX
             << ","
             << " "
             << coordY
             << ")"
             << " "
             << ":"
             << detectedColor;
}

void UviColorPicker::initBackgroundGradient()
{
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient=QLinearGradient(0,
                                                        0,
                                                        256,
                                                        0);
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setSpread(QGradient::PadSpread);
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.00,
                                                   QColor(255,
                                                          0,
                                                          0));
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.20,
                                                   QColor(255,
                                                          255,
                                                          0));
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.40,
                                                   QColor(0,
                                                          255,
                                                          0));
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.60,
                                                   QColor(0,
                                                          255,
                                                          255));
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(0.80,
                                                   QColor(0,
                                                          0,
                                                          255));
    this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient.setColorAt(1.00,
                                                   QColor(255,
                                                          0,
                                                          255));
}

void UviColorPicker::initForegroundGradient()
{
    this->colorPickerForegroundGradient=QLinearGradient(0,
                                                        0,
                                                        256,
                                                        0);
    this->colorPickerForegroundGradient.setSpread(QGradient::PadSpread);
    this->colorPickerForegroundGradient.setColorAt(0.00,
                                                   QColor(255,
                                                          255,
                                                          255,
                                                          0));
    this->colorPickerForegroundGradient.setColorAt(1.00,
                                                   QColor(255,
                                                          255,
                                                          255,
                                                          255));
}
```

Then, I add this image provider to `QML` and register it in `QML` context (in `main.cpp`):

```
UviColorPicker* uviColorPicker=new UviColorPicker(qApp);

engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("uviColorPicker"),
                        uviColorPicker);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uviColorPicker",
                                         uviColorPicker);
```

On `QML` side, I have [Image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html) and its [MouseArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html), from which I call `uviColorPicker.getColorFromCoordinates(mouseX, mouseY);` on mouse click:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Rectangle
{
    id: rootRectangle

    color: "transparent"

    RowLayout
    {
        id: rootLayout

        anchors.fill: parent

        spacing: 8

        Image
        {
            id: colorPickerImage

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

            antialiasing: true

            smooth: true

            mipmap: true

            source: "image://uviColorPicker/colorPickerImage"
        }   // colorPickerImage (Image)

        MouseArea
        {
            id: colorPickerImageMouseArea

            anchors.fill: parent

            hoverEnabled: true

            cursorShape: Qt.CrossCursor

            onClicked:
            {
                uviColorPicker.getColorFromCoordinates(mouseX,
                                                       mouseY);
            }   // onClicked
        }   // colorPickerImageMouseArea (MouseArea)
    }   // rootLayout (RowLayout)
}   // rootRectangle (Rectangle)

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;autoSize:true;formeditorZoom:0.75;height:256;width:256}
}
##^##*/
```

And, why do I get black image instead of gradiented one:
[image: Black image instead gradient]

Comment: I guess that `Gradient` doesn't provide option to pick a color. You have to implement the palette item by yourself (C++) and provide such option. There is [ColorDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-colordialog.html#details) that can do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have forgotten to setup initial size of [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#details), used in class and initalized in construtor. This modification works:

```
UviColorPicker::UviColorPicker(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                          QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading),
      colorPickerGraphicsScene(new QGraphicsScene(0,
                                                  0,
                                                  256,
                                                  256,
                                                  this)),
      colorPickerImage(QImage(QSize(256,
                                    256),
                                    QImage::Format_ARGB32))
{
    this->colorPickerImage.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter gradientPainter(&this->colorPickerImage);

    gradientPainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    this->initBackgroundGradient();
    this->initForegroundGradient();

    this->colorPickerBackgroundBrush=QBrush(this->colorPickerBackgroundGradient);
    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->setBackgroundBrush(this->colorPickerBackgroundBrush);

    this->colorPickerForegroundBrush=QBrush(this->colorPickerForegroundGradient);
    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->setForegroundBrush(this->colorPickerForegroundBrush);

    this->colorPickerGraphicsScene->render(&gradientPainter);
}
```

and now Color Picker is visible on QML size and I can select color at `(x,y)` coordinates of mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

While there are lots of ways to do what you want, here is a solution that is done in terms of QML+Canvas.

Idea is quite similar to that you've said in comment:

- Grab a screenshot / store static image (e.g. after width/height change) using `Item`'s [`grabToImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) method.
- Draw stored image on [`Canvas`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) using `Context2d`'s [`drawImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#drawImage-method-2) method.
- On mouse move:

  - Extract [`CanvasImageData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvasimagedata.html) at position `mouseX`, `mouseY` via [`getImageData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#getImageData-method) method.
  - Having 1px x 1px = 1px `CanvasImageData` (that is one-dimensional array containing the data in RGBA order, as integers in the range 0 to 255) extract pixel color and store it as `currentColor` (to set color you can use [`Qt.rgba`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#rgba-method)).
  - Use your `currentColor` as you want.

Whole example application implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/grab_qml_item_pixel_color).